# Sublime Snippet Not Working

Tags: sublimetext3

I was just trying to make some snippets but I can't get any of them to work. Can anyone see what's wrong with this? I read their docs and thumbed some examples off the web but they don't work either.  I've got it in my `/sublime text 3/packages/user` folder and it's named using convention `myTest.sublime.snippet`.

The snippet is:

```
<snippet>
    <content>
<![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html lang="en">
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>${1:test1|test2|test3} | $2</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="Description" lang="en" content="Description">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta name="robots" content="noodp, noydir">

    <!-- Twitter Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->    
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        $3
    </div>

</body>
</html>
]]>
</content>
    <tabTrigger>page</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.html</scope>
    <description>HTML5 Base HTML</description>
</snippet>
```

Comment: The naming convention is `*.sublime-snippet`. Try fixing that first, unless it was a typo in your question. If it still doesn't work, run the `show_scope_name` command on a file, what scopes appear? I don't know all of the key bindings for this command, you can either look for it or enter `view.run_command("show_scope_name")` in the ST console.

Comment: Wow, embarrassing! It was just missing the dash, thanks for the help!  Not sure how to mark this as the best answer.  Thanks for all the help Skuroda and Soon.  Cheers!!!

Comment: See the scope first using following command. ```view.scope_name(view.sel()[0].begin())``` in sublime console. To bring up sublime console type Ctrl+` in MacOs

Comment: When I send the command `view.scope_name(view.sel()[0].begin())` in the console,it returns `text.xml meta.tag.xml punctuation.definition.tag.end.closing.xml `. In my snippet, the scope is set as `<scope>text.md</scope>`.

Have I set the scope incorrectly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `text.html` instead of `source.html` in `scope` block.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.  I replaced source.html with text.html and it still doesn't show the snippet when I tab after typing page :(

Comment: Try to make a folder named `HTML` in `Packages/User` and place snippet into it.

Comment: Yah, still doesn't work.  I can't even hit "New Snippet" and get the hello world example to work with me just uncommenting the bottom tags, but all the built in ones work just fine.

Comment: Strangely. I copy-pasted your example into `HTML` folder, change `source` to `text` and the snippet works. Try to unzip the default `HTML.sublime-package`, change something in snippet, place it in `User` or `User/HTML` folder and try to call. Also try to restart ST3.

Answer (score 13):

Sublime 3 needs snippets to have .sublime-snippet endings in file name.

Answer (score 8):

Step1. For html snippet, please change

```
<scope>source.html</scope>
```

to

```
<scope>text.html</scope>
```

Step2. If you want sublime to show tooltips after you input the keywords, add this line

```
"auto_complete_selector": true
```

to your Preferences - Settings User file

Answer (score 7):

You should escape dollar signs in your snippet. $ -> \$.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and what I did was :

**Just remove** `<scope>source.html</scope>` line present at the bottom of the snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Remove:

> <description>HTML5 Base HTML</description>

Yes, this line comes from the official documentation, but at least in my instance (Sublime 3, Build 3114), it breaks the snippet. When I remove that line, the snippet works.

Also, as Jinglong above answered, add the following to your user preferences:

> "auto_complete_selector": true

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly an old thread, but it came up when I was searching on creating sublime snippets. The initial issue might be that you are typing in "page" as your tab trigger without first setting your syntax to html. You can do this quickly with shift + command/control + p then type sshtml then enter. Try your tab trigger again. Worked for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

### solved by..

- removing `<scope>source.html</scope>`
- adding `"auto_complete_selector": true,` to user settings

**Background**

My `js/` snippets worked fine with `<scope>source.html</scope>` but for whatever reason, that line caused issues in my `html/` snippets not.

Comment: So, just be sure _not_ to follow the official documentation, and you'll be fine!
I removed both <scope> and <description> and my snippet worked. (I didn't have to set the scope either.)
I had to restart ST for it to show up in the snippets toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem!  I have been using the unicode setting for my keyboard for another project.  When I changed my keyboard back to US, my problem was resolved.  I'm sure this is an unusual issue, but in case anyone else is having this problem:

changing the keyboard back to US also reactivated some of the code navigation shortcuts (e.g., jumping word-to-word on a line by holding down option + arrow keys)